# Jquery ui-widget css override

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery autocomplete and would like to override some of the css styles used in it but I am not able to do so. The input font size is 1 em and the font:weight is bold which I don't want. so how do I change the font size and font weight.

here are the css classes that I want to change. I put all font sizes to 0.5 em but it is not chaniging anything.

```
            /* Component containers
            ----------------------------------*/
            .ui-widget {
                font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
                font-size: 0.5em;
            }
            .ui-widget .ui-widget {
                font-size: 0.5em;
            }
            .ui-widget input,
            .ui-widget select,
            .ui-widget textarea,
            .ui-widget button {
                font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
                font-size: 0.5 !important;
            }
            .ui-widget-content {
                border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: #ffffff url(images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
                color: #222222;
            }
            .ui-widget-content a {
                color: #222222;
            }
            .ui-widget-header {
                border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                background: #cccccc url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
                color: #222222;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .ui-widget-header a {
                color: #222222;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {
    font-size: 0.5em !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;
}
```

If it didn't work please make a fiddle.

Answer (score 9):

First try avoiding using `!important` in your code as it is a bad practice.

Next you are missing the `em` suffix after the units

```
font-size: 0.5 !important;
              ^-------------Missing em
```

should be

```
font-size: 0.5em !important;
                     ^------- get rid of this
```

You always have the option of overriding the styles if you can calculate the [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) properly.

Comment: Thanks for that link to the article about specificity.  It was very helpful.